# Need help to sort my SqlDataSource from a string i have in my .cs file

Tags: c#, html, mysql, asp.net

On my site I have 2 tables where the first table sends a `customerNr` that should control what information is loaded into my second table.

```
protected void DataList2_ItemCommand(object source, DataListCommandEventArgs e)
{
    string tempKundeNr;

        tempKundeNr = e.CommandName;
}
```

`tempKundeNr` gets the correct information but here is my problem: sorting my `sqldatasource` after the string.

What I have below is currently not functioning, but it hopefully shows what I am aiming for.

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource3" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:XXXXX %>"
                    ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:XXXXX.ProviderName %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [XXXXX], [XXXXX], [XXXXX] FROM [XXXXX] WHERE ([OrderNr] = ?)">
    <SelectParameters>

            <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="OrderNr" QueryStringField="tempKundeNr" Type="Int32" />

    </SelectParameters>
  </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Edit*

The table that sends the information i need to sort by:

```
 <asp:DataList ID="OrdersList2" runat="server" CellPadding="4" DataKeyField="OrderNr"
                    DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" ForeColor="#333333"
                    onitemcommand="DataList2_ItemCommand">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <table>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <b>Ordre Nummer: </b>
                                    <asp:Label ID="OrderNrLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("OrderNr") %>'/>
                                    <br /><br />
                                    <b>Kunde:</b>
                                    <asp:Label ID="KundeLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("XXX") %>' />
                                    <br />
                                    <b>Ønsket afhentningstid:</b>
                                    <asp:Label ID="HentwLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("XXX") %>' />
                                    <br />
                                    <b>Total Pris:</b>
                                    <asp:Label ID="PrisLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("XXX") %>' />
                                    <br /><br />
                                    <asp:Button ID="btnwinfo" runat="server" CssClass="button" Text="Se Mere" CommandName='<%# Eval("OrderNr") %>' CommandArgument='<%# Eval("OrderNr") %>'  />

                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:DataList>
```

Comment: Have you tried to use `Order by` after `where` clause?

Comment: I tried that, but that is only the sorting order?, the string tempKundeNr will get a number when a button is clicked, and if that is 6 then i want the sql to only get information where OrderNr is = 6

Answer (score 0):

Well, you need to put the parameter in `where` clause (see below):

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource3" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:XXXXX %>"
                    ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:XXXXX.ProviderName %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [XXXXX], [XXXXX], [XXXXX] FROM [XXXXX] WHERE [OrderNr] = @orderNr">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Here I put `@orderNr` parameter.

Then you can pass this parameter in your button click handler:

```
SqlDataSource3.SelectParameters.Add("orderNr", DbType.SomeType, someValue);
```

and this parameter will be passed to you select query.

You even can specify you `select` query in code-behind (if necessary):

```
SqlDataSource3.SelectCommand = "SELECT [XXXXX], [XXXXX], [XXXXX] FROM [XXXXX] WHERE [OrderNr] = @orderNr";
```

Hope it will help.

Comment: iam having issue getting 
SqlDataSource3.SelectParameters.Add("orderNr", DbType.SomeType, someValue);
placed correctly (does it require specific using?), i have added the table that sends the information to my original post.